# PHPMailer returns SMTP error with Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, phpmailer

I have a simple form set up with AJAX and PHP. This all works when I type the unix command `php send_nl.php`, but every time it returns a SMTP error from the ajax request.

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

**newsletter.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#risultato tbody').on( 'click', '.invianl', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: includes/api_send_nl.php, 
            type: "POST", 
            data: {}
        }).done(function(json) {
            alert(json);
        }).fail(function(data) {
            alert( "error" +data );
        });

        console.log(jqxhr);
        return false;
    });
});
```

**includes/api_send_nl.php**

```
require "common.php" ;
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$id = 2;
//$email_id=$_GET['email_id'];

//function sendMail($id){
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Port = 25;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

$stmt=$db->prepare("select * from newsletter_email where email_id='$id'");
if (!$stmt) {
    log_msg($db->error);
    die();
}
if (!test_execute($stmt->execute())) die("ERRORE QUERY 2");
$newsletter=fetchArray($stmt);
$stmt->close();
$newsletter=$newsletter[0];

$mail->setFrom($newsletter['from_email'], $newsletter['from_name']);
$mail->addAddress('info@mydomain.com');
$mail->addReplyTo($newsletter['replyto_email'], $newsletter['replyto_name']);

$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = $newsletter['subject'];
$mail->Body    = $newsletter['body'];
$mail->AltBody = 'Se non riesci a visualizzare la mail, clicca qui';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
//}
```

Comment: You need to provide username / pass

Comment: Following the link in the error message might help you. Set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;`. Since you're connecting to localhost (which is unlikely to need a user/pass), this suggests you don't have a local mail server running. Though you check for errors, you don't check that the query actually found anything.

Comment: Thanks to $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; I discovered this issue:
"PHPMailer SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Settings `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` I discovered this issue:

```
PHPMailer SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Permission denied (13)
```

And I solved with: https://gistpages.com/posts/phpmailer_smtp_error_failed_to_connect_to_server_permission_denied_13_fix